# WHY is the fs.rmdir recursive option experimental?

Tags: node.js, fs

I see that since version 12, NodeJS has had a `recursive` option on the `fs.rmdir` function to allow removal of non-empty directories from the file system. Why is this feature marked "experimental" in the documentation? Does it work or doesn't it? The documentation doesn't say what level of concern to have over this, or under what circumstances.

I found [Christopher Hiller's article](https://boneskull.com/recursive-directory-removal-in-node-js/) explaining the difficulties that went into creating an efficient implementation of this, but he doesn't explain the "experimental" designation. Maybe the problem isn't that it doesn't work, or doesn't always work, but that it can be a bottleneck under certain circumstances? I'm trying to decide whether to depend on it or not, rather than writing my own code that's going to have exactly the same pitfalls Hiller encountered, so if anyone here has any insight, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: If you look at [its implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/rimraf.js), you will see that it has all sorts of retry logic around very specific types of errors.  My guess is that they aren't really sure if this is bulletproof logic on all the platforms and thus they are "trying" it out for now - essentially a "beta".  Believed to work, but not widely run through the ringer by lots of developers on lots of platforms with lots of file systems in lots of situations.  That would be my guess.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what developer feedback has been in the five or six months since the feature went live. I don't see any issues reported on it in the GitHub project except for a case where it was hanging when an invalid character was present.